# Sharing database connection between multiple processess with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, multiprocess

I am using Python's `multiprocessing` for the first time to launch a certain number of processes (8) to run some queries periodically on a large number a of tables (around 1000 tables).

Each query should be run periodically. Every 300 seconds, for example.

Of course, I want to create a database connection pool to share the database connection between these processes.

As you can see in the code below, I create one process per table. I create a Pool with `cx_Oracle`, and use `acquire()` before the process starts executing its query and `release()` when it has finished executing it.

This is roughly what I have for the moment:

```
import cx_Oracle
import multiprocessing as mp


class OracleWatcher(mp.Process):
    """Oracle Data Base Watcher."""

    def __init__(self, process_config):
        """Initialisation."""
        self.table_name = process_config["table_name"]
        self.query_str = process_config["query_str"]
        self.check_interval = process_config["check_interval"]
        super(OracleWatcher, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        """Run method. Executed when creating a Process."""
        db_connection = pool.acquire()

        result = self.run_my_query(self.table_name, self.query_str)

        pool.release(db_connection)

        time.sleep(self.check_interval)

        self.run()

        return


db_user = get_database("user")
db_pass = get_database("pass")
db_host = get_database("host")
db_port = get_database("port")
db_name = get_database("name")

dsn_str = cx_Oracle.makedsn(db_host, db_port, db_name)

max_pool_size = 8 # 8 processes can use the connection pool simultaneously
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user=db_user,
                             password=databases_info["DB1"]['pass'],
                             dsn=dsn_str,
                             min=min_pool_size,
                             max=max_pool_size,
                             increment=increment)

jobs = []
database_tables = get_database_tables()

for database_table in database_tables:

    table_config_dict = {}

    table_config_dict["check_interval"] = get_table_name()
    table_config_dict["check_interval"] = get_check_interval()
    table_config_dict["query_str"] = get_query_str()

    proc = OracleWatcher(table_config_dict)
    jobs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for j in range(len(jobs)):
    jobs[j].join()
```

Is it enough to just use `acquire()` and `release()` to share the connection between processes and to only allow 8 of them to use it simultaneously? Am I missing something? Do I need to use something like `multiprocessing.Queue()`?

Comment: Did you get anything on it or your code is working already?